# Ford Falcon 1999 Radio won't let me press any keys to enter security code

Tags: electrical, audio, security, falcon

This was actually an issue before the reset. All of the buttons on the radio stopped working except for the volume knob.

I figured this was a battery problem. It's a pretty old car and maybe not enough electricity was getting to the radio or something?

I ended up replacing my battery after it died completely over the summer, and now it's asking me to enter a code for the radio.

But again, none of the buttons will do anything at all. I can't seem to enter the code in. I've tried pushing and holding down every button on the radio, along with various combinations of buttons. Nothing seems to do anything.

The rest of the car works fine.

Is there any way for me to fix something like this? I don't have enough money to properly take it in to a mechanic, but I'm pretty good with electronics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this is definitely not a good solution, but I gave the radio a good, solid whack and that seemed to do the trick.

I guess maybe just a loose wire or something?